# Messed up after installing Unity8/Unity mir

Tags: unity, mir

i recently installed Unity 8/Unity mir desktop from terminal using command provided on OMG Ubuntu. But now i can't go back to my original unity desktop. My pc is on auto login at start-up so i can't change my desktop from login screen :(

I can't logout, restart, shutdown or open terminal :(

Any suggestions?

Comment: Can you get to a command line by pressing CTRL+ALT+F1? (Or F2, F3...)? In that case you can do `sudo apt-get autoremove unity8-desktop-session-mir` and `sudo rm /etc/lightdm/lightdm.conf.d/unity8` and reboot, as suggested on the OMG Ubuntu site.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to install Unity 8?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/447891/how-to-install-unity-8)