# How do I test unity 8 in 15.10?

Tags: unity

I have a 15.10 installed on a machine since the beta release. Today (official release of 15.10) I did an update. I thought I would have been able to test unity 8.

But the greeter is the same and I don't know how to launch the unity 8 session.

Old questions about unity 8 are not an option, since today Canonical says that "In 15.10, Unity8 is demonstrating Canonical’s convergence vision as a tech preview.  Users can log into a Unity8 session on the desktop, experience the new features, and cleanly revert to the default Unity7 experience."

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can you run unity8 as your desktop?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/439539/can-you-run-unity8-as-your-desktop)

Comment: @dobey That question was old. The answer points to unity8-desktop-session which has not a serie for wily.

I see that there is a package called unity8-desktop-session-mir. I don't know if I have to use that. It seems improbable to me that Canonical says "users can log into..." if this was the path to go.

Comment: Unity 8 is not part of the default install. You must install the packages to get the session. I added a new answer to the other question. You need to install the `ubuntu-touch` package (this is the same seed package used to build the phone images). However, this won't install all the default apps, which come from the app store, on the phone; only the debian packages installed by default in the phone images.

Comment: Doing an install of package `ubuntu-touch` requires fixing unmet dependencies. I did some not-well-understood choices in `aptitude` and this resulted in an unbootable system.

I re-installed and I am giving up the unity 8 testing.

Comment: You have to scroll down a bit but this one explains it pretty well http://askubuntu.com/questions/447891/how-to-install-unity-8

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to install Unity 8?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/447891/how-to-install-unity-8)

Answer (score 1):

Im pretty sure you can install it with sudo apt-get install unity8, whether you can easily swap between it is another thing entierly